# Word frequently used in conjunction with obfuscation?

Tags: single-word-requests

What is a word frequently used with obfuscation? For example “Fox News frequently uses the tactics of obfuscation and_” ?

Comment: You'll need to give us a clue about what you want the word to mean.

Comment: To deliberately make unclear, confusing; and its meaning is similar to obfuscate.

Comment: That's already part of "obfuscation". But as a matched pair - [obfuscation and confusion](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22obfuscation%20and%20confusion%22&tbm=bks&lr=lang_en&gws_rd=ssl), or perhaps [obfuscation and prevarication](https://www.google.com/search?lr=lang_en&tbs=lr%3Alang_1en&tbm=bks&ei=qqerW-DSMNmdhwPFjKiQBQ&q=%22obfuscation+and+prevarication%22&oq=%22obfuscation+and+prevarication%22&gs_l=psy-ab.3...50233.51758.0.52372.13.8.0.0.0.0.459.1021.2-2j0j1.3.0....0...1c.1.64.psy-ab..12.0.0....0.0t08gTrAhPs).

Comment: Thanks for your first question.  Rather than add a comment, please update your question with the clarification requested by the comment.  This helps the next person looking at the question because they don't have to read all of the comments to know more about your question.

Comment: When someone buries an answer with “smoke and mirrors” lengthy, confusing explanations, tangential speech purposefully designed to bewilder and confuse. I’ve used it many times always in conjunction with the word obfuscate. I can’t remember it and I have a bad case of OCD and going through the alphabet is helping this morning.

Comment: Obfuscation and obscurantism? I don't know if that's tautologous.

Comment: When a question asks for help remembering something you have forgotten, it is subjective – a request for guesses or ideas, with the key criterion for answer correctness buried in the mind of the asker. This is not a good fit for the Stack Exchange model. A Stack Exchange question is objective enough to have a clearly “right” answer no matter who is asking. Otherwise, the answer is not useful to future visitors, and we are guessing when we answer or cast votes.

Comment: See: “[Let’s Play The Guessing Game – Stack Overflow Blog](https://stackoverflow.blog/2012/02/lets-play-the-guessing-game/)”, and “[Real Questions Have Answers – SE Blog](https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/01/17/real-questions-have-answers/)”.
A welcoming place to ask for help remembering a word you have forgotten is our [English Language & Usage Chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/95).

Answer (score 2):

Here are some combinations found in books:

- obfuscation and anonymisation
- obfuscation and popular propaganda
- obfuscation and manipulation
- obfuscation and distortion

Comment: I like the last two - also "obfuscation and deception".

Comment: As well as "obfuscation and misdirection."

Answer (score 1):

**Subterfuge**, according to [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/subterfuge):

> a trick or a dishonest way of achieving something

I knew it would come to me! My synapses maybe old but they work now and again.

Obfuscation and subterfuge!

Answer (score 0):

Seeing your example - a news outlet (a news agency would not want to deliberately or obviously lie), two less obvious manipulations that come to mind are "**misrepresentation**" and "**distortion**". I do see that there are others that could easily be used such as "**evasion/avoidance**" or "**exaggeration**" as well. Not sure what might pair best with obfuscation, but maybe the number of syllables will help.

https://www.thefreedictionary.com/misrepresentation

https://www.thefreedictionary.com/exaggeration

https://www.thefreedictionary.com/distortion

https://www.thefreedictionary.com/evasion

Answer (score 0):

You might try ***sophistry***

Defined by [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/sophistry) as:

> the clever use of arguments that seem true but are really false, in order to deceive people